# What does this Op-Amp circuit do?

Tags: sensor, operational-amplifier

I am examining the st-micro rtd circuit for the STM32373C-EVAL kit. What does this circuit do?

Can I use it to support both pt100 and pt1000 rtd elements? The circled area is the point of confusion.

[image: op-amp-circuit]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZXDe.jpg

Comment: Also for reference, this section of the circuit is discussed in the User Manual on page23. http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/USER_MANUAL/DM00062928.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This circuit is a precision constant current source for the PT100 (R30 in the schematic).  This is a Howland current source (principles of operation [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa474/snoa474.pdf)).

If you use *as is* it with PT1000, it would work in general.  You might see  more self-heating.  The output would rail at a lower temperature.

The current is inverse-proportional to R3x**.  You can reduce the current by increasing R3x.

** The designator is obscured by the black circle.  The resistor is directly above JP18.